# Bundle node express.js app into one file and manage the require using gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, bundle, browserify, rollup

I've been trying to bundle a rest api with node.js, express.js and mongoose into one file, nor browserify neither rollup worked for me, i keep having problems of dependencies that are not found as a module requires another, can someone help, even with a tutorial please? 
for exemple with browserify i get the error :

```
var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Function.create (<anonymous>)
```

with rollup or gulp-concat-js i have module not found errors

Comment: As far as I know there is such possibility with webpack. It is quite good. I found good tutorial https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I. This post is somewhat old , so you probably need to tweak configuration to use new Webpack 3 syntax.

Comment: i try to avoid webpack for this case (node.js app), i drove me crazy, docs i found in internet of webpack were more for web apps

Comment: That is true. Bundling is mainly used for frontend web apps, so most of the configurations and tutorials are about them. You can try developing your server without bundling files. It is not required.

Comment: I have got same problem with browserify.